# PySpark batch job's configuration submitted through Apache Livy have no effect

Tags: apache-spark, livy

I submitted spark batch job through Livy to the remote cluster with the following request body.

```
REQUEST_BODY = {
    'file': '/spark/batch/job.py',
    'conf': {
        'spark.sql.legacy.allowCreatingManagedTableUsingNonemptyLocation': 'true',
        'spark.driver.cores': 1,
        'spark.driver.memory': f'12g',
        'spark.executor.cores': 1,
        'spark.executor.memory': f'8g',
        'spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors': 4,
    },
}
```

And in the python file containing application to be run, the SparkSession is created using the following command:

```
-- inside /spark/batch/job.py --
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

// spark application after this point using the SparkSession created above
```

The application work just fine, but the spark acquire all of the resources in the cluster neglecting the configuration set in the request body .

I am suspicious that the */spark/batch/job.py* create another SparkSession apart from the one specifying in the Livy request body. But I am not sure how to use the SparkSession provided by the Livy though. The document about this topic is so less.

Does anyone facing the same issue? How can I solved this problem?

Thanks in advance everyone!